# How are Android News Apps built that get updated as soon as new news come in?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, xml, cordova

Almost all of the news sites have there Android Apps which show the news as soon as they are posted on website. How is this data migrated to APP. Do they take an RSS/XML feed and parse it or JSON/JSONP.

I am looking to built an APP for a news Site which just gives me RSS feed and nothing else, I have no control over this website. How do I built an Android APP for this Site given that I have just an XML feed from them.

The technologies available  to me are JavaScript. So I would want to built this in JavaScript.

I am new to this so please bear with me.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I'm also looking for this now.

Comment: Try xmlpullparser,  link given below by prince.  I'm also making an rss reader app.  I used DOM for parsing but it's not quite working for me.

Comment: @MaulikSheth: Are you doing it on Cross Domain. I need to parse an XML where I have no control over it, It is just readonly for me. Will XMLPullParser work for me?

Comment: I don't know what cross domain you said meant, I'm just developing for Android. And yes give  xmlpullparser a try,  it's  easy to use then DOM.

Answer (score 0):

They simply parse the XML given by the site:

For XML parsing in android try these tutorials

[Android XML Processing with the XmlPullParser](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html)

[Android XML Parsing Tutorial Using DOM parser](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Also you can develop android apps using javascript,Various platforms are available for it like:

[Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-studio/)

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)